# Strtok on text file leads to seg fault

Tags: c, file, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a text file that reads as follows:

```
5f6
2f6
4f6
```

I'd like to obtain the numbers from that textfile (as chars then convert them to integers using `atol()`

I have the code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    char buf[100];
    char * ptr;
    char * ptr2;
    char * ptr3;
    char * ptr4;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c; 
    int d;

    FILE* file;
    if (strcmp(argv[1],"test.txt") == 0)
    {
        file = fopen("test.txt","r");

        while (fgets(buf,100,file) )

        ptr = strtok(str,"f");
        ptr2 = strtok(NULL," ");
        ptr3 = strtok(NULL,"f");
        ptr4 = strtok(NULL," ");
        a = atol(ptr);
        b = atol(ptr2);
        c = atol(ptr3);
        d = atol(ptr4);
    }

    refresh();
    getchar(); 
    endwin();
    return (0);
}
```

however, the program seg faults but compiles. How would I go about doing this more efficiently (By a method that doesn't seg fault)?

Comment: Is that the exact code? copy and paste it please.

Comment: as you said it compiles post the complete version of code / functions which compile

Comment: If you don't want to post the complete program, then create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Also note that if all lines in the input follows the exact format as shown by the example, then you don't need `strtok` or `strtol`, just read a line, then get the first and the third character to get the digits. Don't overcomplicate things!

Comment: What do you think happens in the `while` loop? It only executes the *first* call to `strtok` in the loop. Oh, and that code won't compile! Please ***copy-and-paste*** code, don't rewrite.

Comment: WTB some curly braces for that while-loop

Comment: Okay full code is posted, my bad I guess a snip bit would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems

1. You don't check if the file opened.

   - After `fopen()` you must ensure that you can read from the file, if `fopen()` fails, it returns `NULL` so a simple

     ```
     if (file == NULL)
         return -1;
     ```

   would prevent problems in the rest of the program.
2. Your `while` loop only contains one statement because it lacks braces.

   - Without the braces your while loop is equivalent to

     ```
     while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file))
      {
         ptr = strtok(buf, "f");
      }
     ```
3. You don't check that `strtok()` returned a non `NULL` value.

   - If the token is not found in the string, `strtok()` returns `NULL`, and you passed the returned pointers to `atol` anyway.

     That would cause undefined behavior, and perhaps a segementation fault.
4. You don't check if there was an argument passed to the program but you still try to compare it to a string. Also potential undefined behavior.

I don't know if the following program will do what you need since it's your own program, I just made it safer, avoided undefined behavior

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char buf[100];
    char *ptr;
    char *ptr2;
    char *ptr3;
    char *ptr4;
    int   a;
    int   b;
    int   c;
    int   d;
    FILE *file;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    if (argc > 1)
     {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (file == NULL)
            return -1;
        while (fgets(buf,100,file) != NULL)
         {
            ptr  = strtok(str,"f");
            ptr2 = strtok(NULL," ");
            ptr3 = strtok(NULL,"f");
            ptr4 = strtok(NULL," ");
            if (ptr != NULL)
                a = atoi(ptr);
            if (ptr2 != NULL)
                b = atoi(ptr2);
            if (ptr3 != NULL)
                c = atoi(ptr3);
            if (ptr4 != NULL)
                d = atoi(ptr4);
         }
     }
    refresh();
    getchar();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, but for some reason c = a and d = b, the values don't seem to change.

Comment: You should intialize then if you want to print them because if then don't change it means that `ptr`* variables where `NULL` and hence `c = atoi(...)` wasn't reached. You need to check the data in the file and if `ptr == NULL` print the value of `buf` to see why.

Comment: Okay so I've fixed that, but an even weirder problem happens now. My program completly skips the first line of the text file "5f6", so doesn't end up reading in 5 and 6 but rather the second line which contains 2 and 6.

Comment: Okay so I just noticed, if I change the text file to "5f6 2f6" i.e.. move the 2f6 to the same line, the code works how it's so posed to. But of course I don't want it to read in this sense, but rather line by line.

Comment: You need to remove the `strtok(NULL, " ");`, why is it there anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, you want to get the digits from e.g.

```
5f6
```

as numbers, that's much more easy than you think. Just read the first and the third character, and convert them to numbers using simple arithmetic.

Example:

```
char line[8];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
{
    int firstDigit = line[0] - '0';
    int secondDigit = line[2] - '0';

    printf("%d %d\n", firstDigit, secondDigit);
}
```

For the example input you show

```
5f6
2f6
4f6
```

the output will be

```
5 6
2 6
4 6
```

---

If you're wondering about the arithmetic, it works because most character encodings (like the most common [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)) keeps the digit characters in a consecutive range. In the example of ASCII, the value for e.g. `'5'` is `53`, and the value for `'0'` is `48`. That means the subtraction of `'5' - '0'` results in `53 - 48` which is equal to `5`.